# how to convert function from Jquery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have an input type file connected to a label ( connected by  `for="uploadFileVideo"`), when I click my label the function in script is supposed to be fired. The problem is that nothing happen when the selection is by class ( ".lbl") only when i use element ID, I want to convert the function in my script to javascript function ( `function justClickedAlbl(){//Do Somthing}` ), maybe it will solve my problem.
Is it possible to convert ?

```
//HTML
     <label id="addVideo" for="uploadFileVideo" class="lbl colors" >Add Video</label>
     <input id="uploadFileVideo" type='file' style="width: 300px; display: none" />
//Script
$(".lbl").click(function (evt) {
//Do something
});
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and show what is not working?

Comment: *maybe it will solve my problem* -- I doubt it, if jQuery isn't working for you, it's because your not using it properly. Perhaps it's the missing parenthesis at the end of your snippet?

Comment: This is not the problem

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$(function(){
   $(".lbl").click(function (evt) {
       // Do something, 
       // here you can do anything you want to 
       // be executed when label is clicked
   });
});
```

You have to attach event when DOM is loaded.

Comment: Done, thanks :) it was mechanical error while copying the code from  OP, So I think it doe not deserve down vote ;)

Comment: Thanks, but how to use it ? I thought about this format : function dodo() and to add my label onclick=dodo()

Comment: if you have separate function called `dodo()` you can call it within `//Do something`

Comment: @George indeed there is was not error in that part, just I've made it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can target the label

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("label[for='uploadFileVideo']").on('click', function(){
         // Your code
    });
});
```